# Uploading Nifi template responds with 403 error + browser logs invalid CORS request

Tags: cors, apache-nifi, haproxy

I set up an experimental sandbox with a simple Nifi 1.9.2 service behind a reverse HAProxy 1.8. Everything is working as expected except for the feature to upload templates. I am not using any form of authentication or certificates at the moment (it's a sandbox)

The proxy set up in HAProxy was easy:

```
backend service-nifi
    # I think this first line is the issue
    http-request set-header Origin http://127.0.0.1:8080
    http-request add-header X-ProxyPort 80
    http-request add-header X-ProxyScheme http
    http-request add-header X-ProxyHost experimental
    server nifi-server 127.0.0.1:8080 check
```

The relevant Nifi properties part is as follows:

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=127.0.0.1
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
# whatever I put next breaks my current setup. I don't understand why yet
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
```

Everywhere I look for the solution behind the invalid request, the answer is always the same: the current version of Nifi has CORS filtering and I am supposed to set the `Origin` header to what Nifi expects it to be. I would guess that it should be as follows (as shown in the `set-header` line):

- scheme: `http`
- host: `127.0.0.1`
- port: `8080`

I have already confirmed with `tcpdump` that the request is being forwarded as intended:
`sudo tcpdump -s 1024 -l -A -i lo 'tcp port 8080' > dump`

Here's my request:

```
21:31:43 IP localhost.38642 > localhost.http-alt: Flags [P.], seq ..., ack ..., win ..., options [...], length ...: HTTP: POST /nifi-api/process-groups/{id}/templates/upload HTTP/1.1
...
POST /nifi-api/process-groups/{id}/templates/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: experimental
User-Agent: Mozilla... Firefox...
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1434591419995738407236256922
Content-Length: 10378
Referer: http://experimental/nifi/
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
X-ProxyPort: 80
X-ProxyScheme: http
X-ProxyHost: experimental
```

This is the response:

```
21:31:43 IP localhost.http-alt > localhost.38642: Flags [P.], seq ..., ack ..., win ..., options [...], length ...: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
...
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 21:31:43 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 20
Server: Jetty(9.4.11.v20180605)

Invalid CORS request
```

I know from the [repository](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/d148fb18540b410361a91f22e421867910d2f7c9/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/web/NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration.java#L125) that POST is not among the accepted methods for the endpoint `/process-groups/*/templates/upload`.

I have also tried to increase the logging level of everything by tweaking the `conf/logback.xml` file to help troubleshoot but the output is overwhelming and it is mostly noise.

I am quite frustrated with this problem. I have read many threads about this issue and I've tried almost everything under the Sun. A lot of examples use NginX or Apache. I don't have that flexibility but I assess that HAProxy is more than enough. My best bet is that there is something I'm not seeing or that I have completely ignored.

Comment: The 403 error is the problem you need to solve, and your CORS config is not causing it. Fix the cause of the 403 error, and you’re likely find your existing CORS config is already working as expected. The only reason the browser logs a CORS error is because most servers typically never add your application-set response headers to 4xx responses. Anyway, no matter what you do with your CORS config, it won’t cause a 403 error. So the cause of the 403 error is somewhere else. Check the server logs on the server side, and see what messages the server is logging before it sends the 403 response.

Comment: 403 is a valid server response for a CORS policy violation.  This is the application preventing a XSS or CSRF taking place.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I found the class that generates the error message (and some other debug-level messages). It has its own logger. I added a logger configuration in the xml file and raised the debug level to DEBUG. I know that the application server is the one generating the 403. It is a well documented "feature" that the Nifi team added that block POSTs on that API endpoint to solve a CVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at your request it's indicating that you're being referred by `http://experimental/nifi/` whereas the origin is `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

If you change the first line you rightly suspected to be the issue to `http://experimental` then the post should go through successfully.

Alternatively, the not-so-correct hacky method would be to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the value `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you faced with NiFi Cross-Site Request Forgery Protection. Here is the link to manual: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#csrf-protection

When you execute authorization request (/access/token) you got two cookies: __Secure-Authorization-Bearer and __Secure-Request-Token.

Value of __Secure-Authorization-Bearer cookie you can use as value for Authorization header or maybe your http client can add it automatically.

And to avoid CSRF security filter you should add to all POST/PUT/DELETE requests header with name Request-Token and value of __Secure-Request-Token cookie.